# Is there an if-let one liner shorthand?

Tags: swift, if-statement, syntax, option-type

I would like to be able to use if-let in a similar fashion to the commonly used if-else shorthand: `<condition> ? <expression1> : <expression2>`. This syntax would look something like this:

```
<let condition creating variable v1> ? <expression using v1> : <expression not using v1>
```

Here is an example of how this syntax might look (doesn't compile):

```
let name: String? = getName()

var dict: [String: String]? = let name = name ? ["name": name] : nil
```

The multi-line equivalent that I know is possible is the following:

```
let name: String? = getName()

var dict: [String: String]?
if let name = name {
  dict = ["name": name]
} else {
  dict = ["error": "no name"]
}
```

but even with this multi-line example, the dict has to be a `var`, whereas the one liner shorthand could be assigned to a `let` constant.

Is there any existing syntax that will accomplish this if-let shorthand? If there isn't is there any reason that Swift doesn't implement this syntax already?

Thanks!

Comment: *the dict has to be a `var`*. No, it has not, `let dict: [String: String]?` is also valid if it's going to be initialized in both branches, even  non-optional `let dict: [String: String]` is valid

Comment: You could do it the Old Swift style: `var dict: [String: String]? =  name == nil ? nil : ["name": name!]` I guess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write this using `map`:

```
let dict = getName().map { name in ["name": name] } ?? ["error": "no name"]
```

The closure parameter is `<let condition creating variable v1>`, and the closure's return value is the `<expression using v1>`. `x.map` returns nil when `x` is nil, so the thing after `??` corresponds to the `<expression not using v1>`.

Instead of `{ name in ["name": name] }`, you can also shorten it to `{ ["name": $0] }`.

---

Note that the `dict` in the "multiline version" can be declared as a `let`:

```
let dict: [String: String]
if let name = getName() {
  dict = ["name": name]
} else {
  dict = ["error": "no name"]
}
```

The compiler is smart enough to see that each branch of the if statement is mutually exclusive, and one of the branches must be executed, so you are not reassigning a `let`.

Comment: I feel that there could be a more readable syntax implemented by Swift, but this works as a one-liner for what I was asking. Thanks for the extra tip, I'd forgotten about that.